# Wiring- Simple for you

Tags: electrical, wiring

Ok I have 2 switches right next to each-other on the box. One does the light in the fan/light combo, and lights above my my medicine cabinets. The other, JUST does the fan. Im tired of people taking showers without use the exhaust fan, so to skip all of the pleading and asking politely, I figured I'd just make one switch do everything. There could possibly be 2 power sources im being told, and something about just cap off the neutral from the switch that is no longer going to be used, and just match up the black and red from there to the switch that will be the only one working. Im not entirely confident in my skills but I know how to NOT kill myself. Just a simple diagram showing either scenario would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Turn off the breaker, open up the switch box and take a look inside (maybe pull the switches out for a better look, while leaving the switches connected).  Then report back here what you find. Then you should get an accurate answer.

Comment: As @Tester101 and add some pics if you really want to be industrious.

Comment: OK, it wont be until later this afternoon. Thanks

Comment: You can also replace it with a humidistat switch, which has a humidity sensor and automatically turns on the fan above a certain level.

Answer (score 1):

How about dropping the cover at the top of the fan and if the neutrals are all connected together (suggesting a single supply)
- disconnect the fan wire from whatever it's connected to and reconnect to whatever the lamp is connected to.
- Cap off the wire(s) you disconnected from the fan wire.
now turning on the light will turn on the fan.